# SSIS Flat File Export - Only need certain rows from file

Tags: ssis

I am using SQL Server 2012 and am trying to import a flat file and store it into the database. The problem I am having is that I only need certain rows in a file that contains much more data.

Here is an example from part of a file which I am trying to import.

```
12/02/2015 09:47:44:917 Rx: Message Header: Ver: 1, MsgType: 1, MsgId: 3 Status: 0x00
TranId: 6, Data ByteCount: 55
Data: 86 A6 4E 0B 6A 64 54 2E 00 50 00 02 00 00 60 1A E0 AD 10 12 BF 07 56 54 20 31 32 42 46 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 CB

Rx Cmd=84, Rsp code=0x00, Device Status=0x50
Sub-Device Index=2
IO Card=0
Channel=0
Manufacturer ID=24602
```

The only values I care about are ones which are delimited by = (Sub-Device Index, IO Card, etc.). In this example, how can I import the file in a way that the value 2 gets inserted into a column for Sub-Device Index, 0 inserted into a column for IO Card, 0 for Channel, etc.?

Comment: It is better that you add text and not picture of it

Comment: I changed it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a script task that reads and parses the file, and either populates SSIS variables for use with an `Execute SQL` task, or the script task can insert them directly into the database.